# why UI-related tasks in iOS have to be performed on the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading

As I got to know, in iOS main queue is the only candidate of the three (main_dispatch_queue, global_dispatch_queue, serial_dispatch_queue) for executing UI related tasks in GCD. I would like to know why is that so.

This might be a more general question than specific to iOS. But prefer an answer in iOS context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

In iOS the event loop runs in main thread.

Inside the main method of main.m, UIApplicationMain() sets up the main event loop.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html